# Its about a syntax in php while inserting data in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, string-concatenation

Why is this syntax used:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, hash) VALUES( 
'". mysql_escape_string($name) ."', 
'". mysql_escape_string(md5($password)) ."', 
'". mysql_escape_string($email) ."', 
'". mysql_escape_string($hash) ."') ") or die(mysql_error());
```

I do not have any confusion about mysql_escape_string , function, however why is `mysql_escape_string($name)`, enclosed within two dots:`. mysql_escape_string($name) .` then it is enclosed within double quotes:`". mysql_escape_string($name) ."` lastly the whole thing is enclosed within a single quote :`'". mysql_escape_string($name) ."'` I got this form the following web resource: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-implement-email-verification-for-new-members/

...Its  a php email verification program.

Comment: dude! Stick the code in code tags!

Comment: You should ignore that tutorial and find something that teaches you how to use `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: Two off-topic tips: use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead of the `mysql` connector. The're safer and faster. Also, add a salt to the `md5($password)` function for safety.

Answer (score 1):

The dot (.) is the glue for string concatenation. It is used also for separating variables:

```
"First part of a string". $myvar ." second part of a string"
```

The double quotes is the way we say that that is a string:

```
123
```

is considered an integer,

```
"123"
```

is considered a string.

And finally the single quote is a part of the mysql syntax that requires the strings to be surrounded by '.

Answer (score 0):

The (.) is concatenating the whole string together. see here [string operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

If you echo'ed the query it would look something like this.

```
INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, hash) 
    VALUES ('Jeff', 'hashedpassword', 'email@email.com', 'somehash')
```

Comment: Exactly! Don't think of the quotes enclosing the `mysql_escape_string` function! The single-quotes are actually just characters inside the string. The double-quotes delimit the strings, and the dots glue everything together. When everything is glued together into a single string the single-quotes will enclose the values, just as this answer shows.

Answer (score 0):

The dot operator is the glue for string concatenation. The double quotes represent the start and end of a string. "string1" . "string2" . "string3" would be equivilant to: "string1string2string3".